# c++ using template and virtual method in one class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a little inheritance/template problem. I'm trying to create an interface `IBinding` which is implemented by a `TcpClient` and a `TcpServer` (there will be 2-3 different TcpServers which differ only in the type of Stream(Socket abstraction) they generate after accepting a connection request.

Here is a simplified example:

Interface:

```
struct IBinding
    {
        virtual ~IBinding() {}

        virtual void bind(const std::string endpoint) = 0;

        virtual void terminate() = 0;
    };

    typedef std::shared_ptr<IBinding> TBindingPtr;
```

Header:

```
#include "IBinding.h"

class TcpServer : public IBinding
{
public:
    TcpServer();
    ~TcpServer();

    virtual void bind(const std::string endpoint);

    virtual void terminate();

};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "TcpServer.h"
#include "StreamTypeA.h"
#include "StreamTypeB.h"

TcpServer::TcpServer()  {   }

TcpServer::~TcpServer() {   }

void TcpServer::terminate() {         }

void TcpServer::bind(const std::string endpointStr)
{
        auto stream = std::make_shared<StreamTypeA>();  // Here I need to use different types depending on the server implementation

}
```

Now, I want to create two instances of a `TcpServer` and call `.bind()` on them, but they should create different types of Streams.

a) As far as I understand, it's not possible to pass a Type to the `bind()` method as an argument in c++

b) Trying to define the `bind` method templated also doesn't work, because it is virtual

```
    template<class TSocket>
    virtual void bind(const std::string endpoint);
```

c) I could probably just create two different implementations of the `TcpServer`

Is there another way? Isn't there a way to do it with templates?

Comment: [OT]: you probably want `const std::string&` instead of `const std::string`.

Comment: if method `bind` cannot be both `template` and `virtual`, class `TcpServer` may be template with a `virtual` method `bind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Template functions are inherently incompatible with virtual dispatch.  You cannot override them.  They can be name hidden, but that won't help you probably.  So you either need to provide virtual functions for each stream type you will use, or create an abstraction for stream types that can be used at the IBinding level.

Comment: Thank you! I do have an `IStream` interface for all stream types, but I still need to create a concrete Stream object within the `bind()` method, so I suppose I have to go with your first suggestion?

Comment: @user66875 - Why do you need to create it within bind?  Why can't it be a parameter?  Generally speaking if you think you need to break the language to get your task done you do not.

Comment: Frankly, I really have to doubt that you need this since your stated plan is to pass the type as a template parameter.  It would be more understandable if you were planning to have the function call figure out the type of a parameter but that's not what your stated objective is.  So just pass it as a pointer or reference to base and be done.